# Git bash gives error "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: eclipse, git, github

While trying to clone repos from github.com, git bash gives "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate". However I'm able to clone the repos using Eclipse just fine.

I tried some work arounds involving certificates suggested in the threads related to the error. But none of them worked, and I can't figure out why it's working on Eclipse but not in git bash (or the GitHub desktop client).

PS: It would also be super helpful if anyone could point to some references on understanding ssl and certificates.

Comment: what tricks did you try specifically? Because just asking git to not care about the certificates themselves should be good enough (only not good *in general* from the security POV). Normally, this can be achieved like this `git -c http.sslVerify=false whatever-you-want-to-do`.

Comment: Turning sslVerify off results in "The requested URL returned error: 403"

Comment: I don't think that's SSL certificate related. SSL certificates (the ones you are telling git to disregard, at least) are used in transport and that one looks like it's higher-level.

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant when you said it may be higher-level?

Comment: Are your operating systems certificates all up to date?

Comment: in order to be able to use HTTPS (as a transport for whatever application you want to use), there's a SSL set up. That's the one that you tell git to not care about who signed a given certificate when you use `git -c http.sslVerify blah blah`. Let's say that's network layer 7 according to OSI... then, one application that one web server is holding inside can throw whatever error it pleases.... that's "higher-level" in my mind and that's where I think it's failing (past the HTTPS set up, say).

Comment: try using `global`...like this: `git config --global http.sslVerify false`. Then do all the stuff u want. before exiting do `git config --global http.sslVerify true`.